# Run a subprocess in administrator mode

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, python-3

I'm trying to add a Wi-Fi network on the Raspberry Pi via bash inside a python script.

I want to run a subprocess in administrator mode inside a python application, does anyone have any suggestions to help me?

I need to edit the file:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The entire command I need to execute is:

```
sudo echo "network={ssid="rede" psk="pass" key+mgmt=WPA-PSK}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script/24257940

Comment: This is a general programming question and does not belong to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm trying to add a wifi network on the raspberry pi via bash inside a python script.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer, I don't know if it is the right one for the application, but it worked.

```py
import subprocess

cmd_permission="sudo chmod 777 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
subprocess.run(cmd_permission, shell=True)
cmd="sudo echo "network={ssid="rede" psk="pass" key+mgmt=WPA-PSK}" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

> **Security Considerations**
> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call a system shell. This means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely be passed to child processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via , it is the application’s responsibility to ensure that all whitespace and metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities.shell=True

> When using , the shlex.quote() function can be used to properly escape whitespace and shell metacharacters in strings that are going to be used to construct shell commands.shell=True

[reference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)